# Chrome iframe source apparently change by themself

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, iframe, devexpress

I have an ASP.Net page containing a TabControl (provided by Devexpress) where each Tab is an IFrame.
My issue is that randomly (about one times per day) one tab change its content and show another (of displayed tabs) content, using google chrome released on may 2014 (this version is the browser version used by customer's infrastructure).
If i read IIS logs i see that starting form a moment one IFrame request (request is periodically sent by client, about one times per minute) disapear and another IFrame request duplicates.
It seems that randomly one iframe change its source and get another iframe's source of the page.

This is my scenario MainPage code behind :

On Page_Load of main page i set each IFrame source by code behind (according to a configuration readen by DB using client static IP as configuration's ID).

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ip = Request.UserHostAddress;
        UserConfig configuration = (new UserConfig(ip)).Read();

        if (!Page.IsPostBack && !Page.IsCallback)
        {
            try
            {

                int numberOfPages = configuration.Tabs.Length;
                int toClear = pgrTabControl.TabPages.Count - numberOfPages;

                while (toClear > 0)
                {
                    pgrTabControl.TabPages.RemoveAt(pgrTabControl.TabPages.Count - 1);
                    toClear--;
                }

                foreach ( Tab tab in configuration.Tabs )
                {
                    TabPage currentPage = pgrTabControl.TabPages[i];

                    currentPage.Text = tab.TabDesc;
                    currentPage.Name = "Page_" + Tab.tabID;

                    switch (i)
                    {
                        case 0: Iframe0.Src = "~/Container.aspx?tabID=" + tab.TabID + "&ID=" + i + "&NumOfPage=" + numberOfPages; break;
                        case 1: Iframe1.Src = "~/Container.aspx?tabID=" + tab.TabID + "&ID=" + i + "&NumOfPage=" + numberOfPages; break;
                        case 2: Iframe2.Src = "~/Container.aspx?tabID=" + tab.TabID + "&ID=" + i + "&NumOfPage=" + numberOfPages; break;
                        case 3: Iframe3.Src = "~/Container.aspx?tabID=" + tab.TabID + "&ID=" + i + "&NumOfPage=" + numberOfPages; break;
                        case 4: Iframe4.Src = "~/Container.aspx?tabID=" + tab.TabID + "&ID=" + i + "&NumOfPage=" + numberOfPages; break;
                        case 5: Iframe5.Src = "~/Container.aspx?tabID=" + tab.TabID + "&ID=" + i + "&NumOfPage=" + numberOfPages; break;
                        case 6: Iframe6.Src = "~/Container.aspx?tabID=" + tab.TabID + "&ID=" + i + "&NumOfPage=" + numberOfPages; break;
                        case 7: Iframe7.Src = "~/Container.aspx?tabID=" + tab.TabID + "&ID=" + i + "&NumOfPage=" + numberOfPages; break;
                        case 8: Iframe8.Src = "~/Container.aspx?tabID=" + tab.TabID + "&ID=" + i + "&NumOfPage=" + numberOfPages; break;
                        case 9: Iframe9.Src = "~/Container.aspx?tabID=" + tab.TabID + "&ID=" + i + "&NumOfPage=" + numberOfPages; break;
                        case 10: Iframe10.Src = "~/Container.aspx?tabID=" + tab.TabID + "&ID=" + i + "&NumOfPage=" + numberOfPages; break;
                        case 11: Iframe11.Src = "~/Container.aspx?tabID=" + tab.TabID + "&ID=" + i + "&NumOfPage=" + numberOfPages; break;
                        case 12: Iframe12.Src = "~/Container.aspx?tabID=" + tab.TabID + "&ID=" + i + "&NumOfPage=" + numberOfPages; break;
                        case 13: Iframe13.Src = "~/Container.aspx?tabID=" + tab.TabID + "&ID=" + i + "&NumOfPage=" + numberOfPages; break;
                        case 14: Iframe14.Src = "~/Container.aspx?tabID=" + tab.TabID + "&ID=" + i + "&NumOfPage=" + numberOfPages; break;
                        case 15: Iframe15.Src = "~/Container.aspx?tabID=" + tab.TabID + "&ID=" + i + "&NumOfPage=" + numberOfPages; break;
                        case 16: Iframe16.Src = "~/Container.aspx?tabID=" + tab.TabID + "&ID=" + i + "&NumOfPage=" + numberOfPages; break;
                        case 17: Iframe17.Src = "~/Container.aspx?tabID=" + tab.TabID + "&ID=" + i + "&NumOfPage=" + numberOfPages; break;
                        case 18: Iframe18.Src = "~/Container.aspx?tabID=" + tab.TabID + "&ID=" + i + "&NumOfPage=" + numberOfPages; break;
                        case 19: Iframe19.Src = "~/Container.aspx?tabID=" + tab.TabID + "&ID=" + i + "&NumOfPage=" + numberOfPages; break;
                        case 20: Iframe20.Src = "~/Container.aspx?tabID=" + tab.TabID + "&ID=" + i + "&NumOfPage=" + numberOfPages; break;
                        case 21: Iframe21.Src = "~/Container.aspx?tabID=" + tab.TabID + "&ID=" + i + "&NumOfPage=" + numberOfPages; break;
                        case 22: Iframe22.Src = "~/Container.aspx?tabID=" + tab.TabID + "&ID=" + i + "&NumOfPage=" + numberOfPages; break;
                        case 23: Iframe23.Src = "~/Container.aspx?tabID=" + tab.TabID + "&ID=" + i + "&NumOfPage=" + numberOfPages; break;
                        case 24: Iframe24.Src = "~/Container.aspx?tabID=" + tab.TabID + "&ID=" + i + "&NumOfPage=" + numberOfPages; break;

                        default: throw new Exception( Resources.exc_ControlNotFound );
                    }

                    i++;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

In my scenario (the site is used by company only in local network) the IP is static and each client need to see at least 25 custom tab.

Then in the Container.aspx page i use Request to get tabID (identify the element to display so tab[0] for an user could display different things from tab[0] of another) and understood what i need to display.
The Container.aspx internally has a UserControl that display data in the correct way.

This is Container.aspx code :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //this variable "tabId" is private class variable (NOT static)
            tabId = Request["tabID"];

            try 
            {
                //this variable "id" is private class variable (NOT static)
                id = Convert.ToInt32 (  Request["ID"] ) ;
            }
            catch {}
            try 
            {
                //this variable "numberOfPages" is private class variable (NOT static)
                numberOfPages = Convert.ToInt32 (  Request["NumOfPage"] ) ;
            }
            catch {}

            if (UCDisplayData != null)
            {
                UCDisplayData.TabId = tabId ;
                UCDisplayData.TabIndex = id ;
                UCDisplayData.NumberOfTab = numberOfPages ;
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception err ) 
        {

        }
    }
```

Then the UCDisplayData uses its property TabId to get the currently TabId on which is binded to and refresh its content (one times every minute) using ASPxCallback and some javascript.
UCDisplayData contains some ASPxTextBox that are populated correctly on Page_Load.
The UpdateCallBack then send to page some JSON that contains fields name and fields values to be updated.
No javascript work on IFrame sources in any part of code.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (this.TabIndex < this.NumberOfTab)
            {       
                   txtData1.Text = data readen form db ;
                   txtData2.Text = data readen form db ;
                   .
                   .
                   txtDataN.Text = data readen form db ;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            LastError = err.Message;

            if (!Page.IsCallback)
                Response.Redirect("Error.aspx");
            else
                ASPxWebControl.RedirectOnCallback("Error.aspx");
        }

    }
```

The update callback code is the below :

```
    protected void UpdateFieldCallBack_Callback(object source, DevExpress.Web.ASPxCallback.CallbackEventArgs e)
    {
        dynamic message = new ExpandoObject();
        try
        {
            string fieldToUpdate = string.Empty;

            message.Control_txtData1 = txtData1.ClientInstanceName;
            message.Control_txtData2 = txtData2.ClientInstanceName;
            .
            .
            message.Control_txtDataN = txtDataN.ClientInstanceName;


            message.txtData1 = data readen form db ;
            message.txtData2 = data readen form db ;
            .
            .
            message.txtDataN = data readen form db ;

            e.Result = Utils.Serialize(message);
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            LastError = err.Message;

            if (!Page.IsCallback)
                Response.Redirect("Error.aspx");
            else
                ASPxWebControl.RedirectOnCallback("Error.aspx");
        }
    }
```

The Utils.Serialize () method :

```
    public static string Serialize ( object toSerialize )
    {
        try
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(toSerialize);
        }
        catch ( Exception err ) 
        {
            return string.Empty ;
        }

    }
```

And then the client side javascrit that updeate the UserControl :

```
Update.OnCallbackComplete = function(s, e) {
var message = deserialize(JSON.parse(e.result));

    window[message.Control_txtData1].SetText(message.txtData1);
    window[message.Control_txtData2].SetText(message.txtData2);
    .
    .
     window[message.Control_txtDataN].SetText(message.txtDataN);
};

function deserialize(_jsonObj) {

    if (!_jsonObj)
        return {};

    var result = {};
    for (var i = 0, len = _jsonObj.length ; i < len  ; i++) {
        var obj = _jsonObj[i];
        var key = _jsonObj[i].Key;
        var value = _jsonObj[i].Value;

        if (key)
            result[key] = (Array.isArray(value)) ? deserialize(value) : value;
        else {
            if (obj && Array.isArray(obj)) {
                var array = [];

                for (var i = 0, len = _jsonObj.length ; i < len ; i++)
                    array.push(deserialize(_jsonObj[i]));

                return array;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
};
```

Has someone idea on why, randomly an iframe get the same content of another ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is too much of code to look through ? Try to minimize your code by removing unnecessary code.

Comment: i suppose that javascript and UpdateCallback is not the cause of issue, so they could be not considered, but i need to show Page_Load sources because is in the execution "path" and i suppose they are related with issue (i image i miss something in page life cycle).

Thanks in advance for help.